# Reverse букв в слове, используя range и append. Golang

Tags: массивы, golang

Задание: реализовать реверс букв в строке (range по массиву rune + append).
По документации append добавляет значение в конец массива.
Как с помощью функции append можно добавить значение в начало, что получился реверс, например, "Hello" --> "elloH".

Код:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func ReverseString(s string) string {   
    newWord := make([]rune, len(s)) 
    fmt.Println(newWord)
    for _, v  := range s {
        fmt.Println(v)
        newWord = append(newWord[0:], v)
    }
    return string(newWord)
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(ReverseString("Hello"))
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/YYLljr0fv_5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот еще одно решение данной задачи:

```
func ReverseWordTwo(s string) string {
    var newWord []rune
    for _, v := range s {
        newWord = append([]rune{v}, newWord...)
    }

    return string(newWord)
}
```

Comment: Насколько я могу судить, этот вариант выделяет новый массив под срезом на каждой итерации.

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/6qdakzy0Zdp.  Хотя, если это какое-то учебное задание, то и фиг с ним.

Comment: И что делает сама функция?
Что значат результаты функции `testing.AllocsPerRun`?

Comment: Показывает число выделений памяти.  [Документация](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#AllocsPerRun).

Answer (score 1):

Задание, конечно, довольно странное, но как-то так:

```golang
func ReverseString(s string) string {
    var l = len(s)
    var rev = make([]rune, l)
    for i, r := range s {
        _ = append(rev[:l-1-i], r)
    }

    return string(rev)
}
```

Дисклеймеры про то, что, когда мы говорим
об интернационализованном тексте, всё не так просто, думаю,
не нужны.

https://play.golang.org/p/yXAPldfXRSR

Comment: Объясните почему вы использовали пустой идентификатор перед `= append(...)` ?

Comment: Во-первых, чтобы явно показать, что это не опечатка, а (глупое) использование `append` для перезаписи элемента.  Во-вторых, иначе не пропустит `go vet`, а статические анализаторы надо слушать.